# Showing categories and subcategories in a menu

Tags: php

What is the best way for Showing categories and subcategories in a menu with php?
I have found a function [here](http://www.codeassembly.com/How-to-display-infinite-depth-expandable-categories-using-php-and-javascript/), But I cant understand the logic of $has_childs .
why

```
 $has_childs = false;
```

and then

```
 if ($has_childs === false)
     {
         $has_childs = true;

     }
```

?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That variable means if the main link has any sub-categories. For example, a 'home' button would not have a dropdown, in other words, no child elements related to it. Whilst anything that did have a dropdown WOULD have child elements.

For more information you should google Parent/Child terminology in web programming.